# Is Serilog DiagnosticContext thread safe?

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

I am working on a prototype logging solution using Serilog in ASP.NET Core 3.1 and one of my requirements is the ability to log the entire HTTP request and response payload. To do this, I am writing my own middleware and instead of creating a whole new log entry for this data, I would like to associate the request and response payload with the current log context via Serilog's `IDiagnosticContext / DiagnosticContext` in https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-hosting

I've been studying the code a bit and it appears it is thread-safe by way of the [AmbientDiagnosticContextCollector class](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-hosting/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Extensions.Hosting/Extensions/Hosting/AmbientDiagnosticContextCollector.cs) and the [System.Threading.AsyncLocal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1?view=netcore-3.1) that it utilizes.

Is my understanding of this correct or am I missing something that I should be accounting for?